# Изменить стиль содержания innerHTML

Tags: html, css

Помогите сделать padding-top текста "ТИП ДОКУМЕНТА: ПРИХОД", в коде:

```
<div id="changeview"><input id="inp" disabled  type="text" placeholder="0" name="input" size="46" style="text-align: right;"></div> 

<input type="button" name="vz" value="ВЗ"style="background: #434755; color: white;" onclick="document.getElementById('changeview').innerHTML='ТИП ДОКУМЕНТА: ПРИХОД' ">
```

*кнопкой меняем значение внутри блока.* Пытался сделать отступ сверху через блок #changeview, но само собой что идёт отступ блока, а надо отступ текста от верхней границы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Текст сам по себе не может иметь padding. Это свойство для элементов. 

В вашем случае грубое решение будет таким:

```js
//addEventListener - это страшное слово значит "добавить событие" → у нас "Клик"
//и запустить функцию при клике. 
//Когда начнете писать коды длиннее одной строки, так будет правильнее
document.getElementById('hide').addEventListener('click',function(){
  document.getElementById('changeview').innerHTML = '<div style="padding-top: 25px;">ТИП ДОКУМЕНТА: ПРИХОД</div>';
});
```

```css
/* CSS */
.btn {background-color: #434755; color: white;}
#inp {font-size: 20px; text-align: right;}
```

```html
<div id="changeview">
  <input id="inp" type="text" placeholder="0" disabled>
</div>

<button id="hide" class="btn">B3</button>
```

Но не ясно, для чего вам этот padding... может он там и не ннада... Потому что возможно его можно было бы заменить на `innerHTML = '<br>ТИП ДОКУМЕНТА: ПРИХОД';`

br - от англ. break - переносит всякое на новую строку.

А отмеченный блок *CSS... Это рубо говоря тот же style="..." только записанный в другом месте. Что позволяет визуально уменьшить размер HTML и легче смотреть код.Чтобы работало, нужно написанное поместить вверху страницы, `<style> вот здесь </style>`

Answer (score 1):

При нажатии на кнопку вы меняете содержимое дива changeview, а именно удаляете input и вставляете свой текст 'ТИП ДОКУМЕНТА: ПРИХОД', в итоге у вас остается контейнер changeview, внутри которого текст, к которому нельзя обратиться, потому что у него нет ни тэгов, ничего. Остается и делать отступ через changeview.
Вы можете дополнить 'ТИП ДОКУМЕНТА: ПРИХОД' вот так: `'<div class=prihod>ТИП ДОКУМЕНТА: ПРИХОД</div>'` (или не "div" а "p", любой нужный тег) и в стилях прописать отступ для класса prihod. Это и будет отступ именно от текста.

Answer (score 0):

Обернув текст блоком и присвоив ему класс возникла проблема с кавычками.

*если кому нибудь пригодится* решил проблему так:

```
<input type="button" name="vz" value="ВЗ"style="background: #434755; color: white;" onclick="removeMess(this) ">

<script>
    function removeMess(th) {
        document.getElementById('changeview').innerHTML='<div class="screentext">ТИП ДОКУМЕНТА: ПРИХОД</div>'
    }
</script>

.screentext{
    font-family: 'Press Start 2P', cursive;
    width: 415px;
    height: 65px;
    background: blue;
    font-size: 21px;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 15px;
    text-align: center;
}
```